# pandas read_csv on a *.dat file delimited with cedilla not splitting into columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

This is my first time working on pandas so pardon my ignorance.
My requirement is to download a file from S3 onto Ec2 and put the dat file onto a dataframe. This is how my input file data looked

```
1Ç70Ç23929Ç4341Ç1111Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ012ÇFillerÇ
1Ç75Ç45555Ç4324Ç2222Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç76Ç23957Ç4334Ç3333Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç72Ç47776Ç4344Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇABÇ014ÇFillerÇ
1Ç73Ç88880Ç4354Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇCDÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç74Ç99991Ç4364Ç5555Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇEEÇ014ÇFillerÇ
```

As the data did not seem to have any encoding or so i decided to use the read_Csv with delimiter as cedilla and store in dataframe.

```
iFldDelim = 'Ç'
tf = pandas.read_csv(itextfile, iFldDelim, nrows = 5,header=None)
```

But for some reason it is not recognizing the same and puts the data in one column.

```
                                        0
0 1Ç70Ç23929Ç4341Ç1111Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ012ÇFi...
1 1Ç75Ç45555Ç4324Ç2222Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFi...
2 1Ç76Ç23957Ç4334Ç3333Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFi...
3 1Ç72Ç47776Ç4344Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇABÇ014ÇFi...
4 1Ç73Ç88880Ç4354Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇCDÇ011ÇFi...
```

The file seems like ASCII and not encoded. I did try using the encoding as UTF-8 and UTF-16 and giving the Unicode value as delimiter that does not work.
I also tried to hardcode the delimiter as 'F' instead of cedilla and run the code thinking the file itself might have some encryption/encoding. But that is not the case, i got my output delimited by 'F'.

With delimiter as 'F'.

```
                                   0       1
0 1Ç70Ç23929Ç4341Ç1111Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ012Ç  illerÇ
1 1Ç75Ç45555Ç4324Ç2222Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011Ç  illerÇ
2 1Ç76Ç23957Ç4334Ç3333Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011Ç  illerÇ
3 1Ç72Ç47776Ç4344Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇABÇ014Ç  illerÇ
4 1Ç73Ç88880Ç4354Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇCDÇ011Ç  illerÇ
```

The file i am loading is a huge one usually and this one runs for a long time. So i am not sure if i encode the file using codec to UTF-8 and then put in dataframe is a wise option.

I tried to create a cedilla delimited file manually and when passed through the same command it worked all fine. I am not able to figure what is going wrong here. Is there a way to figure out if it is encoded?

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
VB

Adopting Edchum advise, i used the below,

```
#file location
dataPath = "C:/Users/Documents/Pytest/"
itextfile = join(dataPath,'sample.dat')

fb = open(itextfile, 'r')
data = fb.read() 
print(data)
tf=pandas.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='Ã‡', header=None)
#tf=pandas.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\Ç', header=None)
print(tf)
```

The data came out like below from the file

```
1Ã‡71Ã‡23929Ã‡44Ã‡5685Ã‡0Ã‡0Ã‡1Ã‡aaÃ‡012Ã‡FillerÃ‡
1Ã‡72Ã‡23953Ã‡40Ã‡3319Ã‡0Ã‡0Ã‡1Ã‡bbÃ‡011Ã‡FillerÃ‡
1Ã‡73Ã‡23957Ã‡43Ã‡7323Ã‡0Ã‡0Ã‡1Ã‡ccÃ‡011Ã‡FillerÃ‡
1Ã‡74Ã‡24006Ã‡41Ã‡6938Ã‡0Ã‡0Ã‡1Ã‡bbÃ‡014Ã‡FillerÃ‡
1Ã‡75Ã‡24140Ã‡45Ã‡0518Ã‡0Ã‡0Ã‡1Ã‡ddÃ‡011Ã‡FillerÃ‡

Output

    0    1      2   3     4   5   6   7   8   9      10  11
0    1  71  23929  44  5685   0   0   1  aa  12  Filler NaN
1    1  72  23953  40  3319   0   0   1  bb  11  Filler NaN
2    1  73  23957  43  7323   0   0   1  cc  11  Filler NaN
```

So using the sep='Ã‡' instead of sep='\Ç' worked. Not sure why it appears this way when i run the script, coz to the naked eye (when i open the sample.dat file) it appears delimited with cedilla symbol.

is there a way to pass the textfile without reading externally onto the pandas.read_csv (StringIO) command? 
I ask this because i wanted to limit the number of rows i read and put in the Dataframe. Say if i want to have only the first few rows i added a Totrows and to have last few i used skiprows. That way to process the huge file with millions of rows it would take minimal time. If this is not possible i ll use a for loop ofcourse. Just wanted to check if there was a way to do without for loop.

Thanks, VB

Comment: Hmm, can you try `pd.read_csv(itextfile, sep=r'\Ç', nrows=5, header=None)` this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `sep='\Ç'` as this works for me:

```
In [35]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""1Ç70Ç23929Ç4341Ç1111Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ012ÇFillerÇ
1Ç75Ç45555Ç4324Ç2222Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç76Ç23957Ç4334Ç3333Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇAAÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç72Ç47776Ç4344Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇABÇ014ÇFillerÇ
1Ç73Ç88880Ç4354Ç4444Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇCDÇ011ÇFillerÇ
1Ç74Ç99991Ç4364Ç5555Ç0Ç0Ç1ÇEEÇ014ÇFillerÇ"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\Ç', header=None)

Out[35]:

   0   1      2     3     4   5   6   7   8   9       10  11
0   1  70  23929  4341  1111   0   0   1  AA  12  Filler NaN
1   1  75  45555  4324  2222   0   0   1  AA  11  Filler NaN
2   1  76  23957  4334  3333   0   0   1  AA  11  Filler NaN
3   1  72  47776  4344  4444   0   0   1  AB  14  Filler NaN
4   1  73  88880  4354  4444   0   0   1  CD  11  Filler NaN
5   1  74  99991  4364  5555   0   0   1  EE  14  Filler NaN
```

Comment: For me it wants `engine='python'` also, because warning.

Comment: @jezrael the non-standard/unsupported separator won't work with the `c` engine so it falls back to `python`

Comment: Yes, but warning is there for me. Do you have warning also?

Comment: @jezrael yes I get warning, I just edited it out of my answer

Comment: Hi ,thanks EdChum and. Using sep did work for me. although my file seems to have a diff delimiter now. This is wht i tried

Comment: can't help unless you post data and code that demonstrates this

Comment: the reply was too long for the comments section so added as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As standard practice you may want to open your docs using the codecs package. This will allow you to specify the encoding (UTF-16 in most cases) and the codecs package seems to be very good at deciphering things like line terminators and encoding.

[Reading tab-delimited file with Pandas - works on Windows, but not on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896214/reading-tab-delimited-file-with-pandas-works-on-windows-but-not-on-mac/38951835#38951835)

```
import codecs

doc = codecs.open('document','rU','UTF-16') (open for reading with "universal" type set)

df = pandas.csv_read(doc, sep='Ç', nrows=Totrows, header=Skiprows)
```