# How to complete this Python script to manipulate data in tab delimited file?

Tags: python-3.x, list, delimiter

I have a list of *Part Numbers* and *Serial Numbers* in a tab-delimited file that I need to merge together using a hyphen to make an *Asset Number*.

This is the **input**:

```
Part Number    Serial Number
PART1          SERIAL1
,PART2         SERIAL2
, PART3        SERIAL3
```

This is what I would like as the **desired output**:

```
Part Number    Serial Number    Asset Number
PART1          SERIAL1          PART1-SERIAL1
,PART2         SERIAL2          PART2-SERIAL2
, PART3        SERIAL3          PART3-SERIAL3
```

I have tried the following **code**:

```
import csv
input_list = []
with open('Assets.txt', mode='r') as input:
    for row in input:
        field = row.strip().split('\t') #Remove new lines and split at tabs
        for x, i in enumerate(field):
            if i[0] == (','):   #If the start of a field starts with a comma
                field[x][0] = ('') #Replace that first character with nothing
                field[x].lstrip() #Strip any whitespace
        print(field)
```

This code produced the **actual output**:

```
['Part Number', 'Serial Number']
['PART1', 'SERIAL1']
['",PART2"', 'SERIAL2']
['", PART3"', 'SERIAL3']
```

My first problem is that my code to remove the commas and whitespace from the start of all fields fails to work.

The second problem is that there are quotation marks that have been added to the whitespaces.

The third problem is that I don't know how to add another item to the list array (*Asset Numbers*) so I can join the fields.

**Would someone please be able to help me solve any of these problems?**

Comment: Your question is awesome, I have solved it. The use of Python's `re` module & `strip()` method defined on string will be very useful. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to strip the commas even if they are not here without problem, so the `if[0] == ",":` is not needed anymore. You also strip a string but the value is not stored in the list. This is fixed here:

```
input_list = []
with open('Assets.txt', mode='r') as text_file:
    for row in text_file:
        field = row.strip('\n').split('\t') # Remove new lines and split at tabs.
        for n, word in enumerate(field):
            field[n] = word.lstrip(", ") # Strip any number of whitespaces and commas.
        print(field)
```

Output:

```
['Part Number', 'Serial Number']
['PART1', 'SERIAL1']
['PART2', 'SERIAL2']
['PART3', 'SERIAL3']
```

So now we can put a `Asset_number = field[0] + '-' + field[1]` somewhere and it will give you the value `PARTx-SERIALx` that you wanted to use.

A little modification to get the desired output:

```
input_list = []
with open('Assets.txt', mode='r') as text_file:
    for m, row in enumerate(text_file):
        field = row.strip('\n').split('\t') # Remove new lines and split at tabs.
        for n, word in enumerate(field):
            field[n] = word.lstrip(", ") # Strip any number of whitespaces and commas.

        if m == 0: # Special case for the header.
            text_to_print = field[0] + '\t' + field[1]  + '\t' + 'Asset Number'
        else:
            Asset_number = field[0] + '-' + field[1]
            text_to_print = field[0] + '\t' + field[1]  + '\t' + Asset_number

        print(text_to_print)
```

And the *printed* output is:

```
Part Number     Serial Number   Asset Number
PART1   SERIAL1 PART1-SERIAL1
PART2   SERIAL2 PART2-SERIAL2
PART3   SERIAL3 PART3-SERIAL3
```

It does not look good here for some reason but the string is still right and the tabs are where they are expected, so you should have no problem writing that to a new file instead of printing it.

```
'Part Number\tSerial Number\tAsset Number'
'PART1\tSERIAL1\tPART1-SERIAL1'
'PART2\tSERIAL2\tPART2-SERIAL2'
'PART3\tSERIAL3\tPART3-SERIAL3'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. As a beginner I like how this answer doesn't require importing of extra modules and is easy to understand.

Comment: Glad to help! Yes me too, I like to know if there is a basic Python solution before trying to use re for strings or panda for data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Part Number': ['PART1',', PART2',',  PART3'],
        'Serial Number': ['Serial1','Serial2','Serial3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[:,'AssetNumber'] = df.loc[:,'Part Number'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip().replace(',','')) + '-' + df.loc[:,'Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip().replace(',',''))
```

This will do what you want

In your case as you are dealing with CSV call

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepathasstring',sep='\t')
```

If you have an issue check this one for issue with rows:

[Reading tab-delimited file with Pandas - works on Windows, but not on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896214/reading-tab-delimited-file-with-pandas-works-on-windows-but-not-on-mac)

Then you can save as tab delimited by calling:

```
df.to_csv('filepathasstring', sep='\t')
```

And here's how to get pandas if you don't have it yet:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code and it perfectly works.

> input.txt

```
Part Number    Serial Number
PART1          SERIAL1
,PART2         SERIAL2
, PART3        SERIAL3
```

> split_text_add_combine.py

```
import re

def split_and_combine(in_path, out_path, new_column_name):
    format_string =  "{0:20s}{1:20s}{2:20s}"
    new_lines = [] # To store new lines

    # Reading input file to process
    with open(in_path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            line = line.strip()
            arr = re.split(r"\s{2,}", line)

            if index == 0:
                # Important to split words in case if words have more than single space
                new_line = format_string.format(arr[0], arr[1], new_column_name) + '\n'
            else:
                # arr = line.split()
                comma_removed_string = (arr[0] + "-" + arr[1]).lstrip(",").lstrip() 
                new_line = format_string.format(arr[0], arr[1], comma_removed_string) + '\n'

            new_lines.append(new_line)

    print(new_lines)

    # Writing new lines to: output.txt
    with open(out_path, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(new_lines)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    in_path = "input.txt"
    out_path = "output.txt"
    new_column_name = "Asset Number"

    split_and_combine(in_path, out_path, new_column_name)
```

> output.txt

```
Part Number         Serial Number       Asset Number        
PART1               SERIAL1             PART1-SERIAL1       
,PART2              SERIAL2             PART2-SERIAL2       
, PART3             SERIAL3             PART3-SERIAL3
```

> References:

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format
- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip