# Python: str.split() not working with "\t" imported from text file

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, tabs

I am writing code where a user must define the separator used to read in columns from a large text file (too large to hold in memory). That separator is read in via a text file imported via the Pandas module.

Consider the following test code:

```
import pandas

table_file = 'test.txt'
input_file = 'test_input.txt'

inputs = pandas.read_csv('test_input.txt', sep = '\n', dtype = str)
inputs = inputs['Inputs']
sepa = inputs[0]
print(sepa)

with open(table_file) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line_stripped = line.rstrip('\n')
            line_list_1 = line_stripped.split(sepa)
            line_list_2 = line_stripped.split('\t')
            print(line_list_1)
            print(line_list_2)
```

The file "test.txt" contains:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   2   3   4           7   8   9   10
```

The file "test_input.txt" contains:

```
Inputs
\t
```

The following lines are printed:

```
\t
['1\t2\t3\t4\t\t\t7\t8\t9\t10']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '', '', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Why is "line_list_2" working correctly while "line_list_1" is not? How can I fix this? Note that the separator must be read in via an input file; I cannot simply define it in the code or read it in via console input. The separator might also be, for example, a comma or a space.

Comment: The file appears to contain the literal digraph `\t`, not a tab character. `'\t'` in your code is a `str` literal containing an escape sequence that produces a literal tab.

Answer (score 2):

Because one is being considered as an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) and another is a literal string. A variable that is defined from reading a text that contains "\t" will not be considering the escape character whereas you creating "\t" will and therefore assign it an alternative behavior (which in this case would be considered as a valid separator for your text). Please have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896214/reading-tab-delimited-file-with-pandas-works-on-windows-but-not-on-mac).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think this is more accurate now?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand what's going on now, but I'm wondering, do you know of a way to convert the "\t" string that is read in to the analogous "\t" which could be used as a separator? In such a way that a read-in separator such as "," or " " would be unaffected by the same process?

The inelegant solution, I suppose, is just to have the user write in "tab" or something in "test_input.txt", have that read in as "sepa_temp", and assign "sepa" to "\t" when "sepa_temp == 'tab'".

Comment: Whoops, even if I write the following within the code:

sepa = '\t'

...The same undesired behaviour pops up.

Comment: Try with `re.compile()`

Comment: Look at `print('\t')` vs `print(r'\t')`?

Comment: Using "re.compile(sepa)" leads to the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    line_list_1 = line_stripped.split(sepa)
TypeError: must be str or None, not re.Pattern

Answer (score 2):

As the answer above states, the text file is passing the literal "\t" and not the escape character. I tried to reproduce your error on Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d7m3-g_JDKJLZRTgVqYShs5G8XkTk8DV?usp=sharing), and found that, at least on this system, the code was run correctly.

```
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J \n\
1   2   3   4           7   8   9   10 ')
    f.close
    
with open('test_input.txt', 'w') as g:
    g.write('Inputs\n\
\\t ')
g.close

import pandas

table_file = 'test.txt'
input_file = 'test_input.txt'

inputs = pandas.read_csv('test_input.txt', sep = '\n', dtype = str)
inputs = inputs['Inputs']
sepa = inputs[0]
print(sepa)

with open(table_file) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line_stripped = line.rstrip('\n')
            line_list_1 = line_stripped.split(sepa)
            line_list_2 = line_stripped.split('\t')
            print(line_list_1)
            print(line_list_2)
```

Prints:

```
\t 
['1   2   3   4           7   8   9   10 ']
['1   2   3   4           7   8   9   10 ']
```

Could you clarify on the details of the system you are trying to run the code on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting the error both in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20. The text input files were written in Notepad on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the ugly workaround I've come up with. The content of "input_test.txt" was changed to:

```
Inputs
tab
```

Meanwhile, the code was changed to:

```
import pandas

table_file = 'test.txt'
input_file = 'test_input.txt'

inputs = pandas.read_csv('test_input.txt', sep = '\n', dtype = str)
inputs = inputs['Inputs']
sepa = inputs[0]

with open(table_file) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line_stripped = line.rstrip('\n')
            if sepa == 'tab':
                line_list_1 = line_stripped.split('\t')
            else:
                line_list_1 = line_stripped.split(sepa)
            line_list_2 = line_stripped.split('\t')
            print(line_list_1)
            print(line_list_2)
```

The correct output is printed:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '', '', '7', '8', '9', '10']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '', '', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

This works because tab is the only separator with an escape character I am reasonably likely to run in to in the context of what I'm doing, but it's not very satisfying.